# Integers modulo prime power, not a graded ring?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, graded-rings

We can decompose Z mod p^n as a vector space over Z mod p by writing numbers base p, eg, mod 3, 52= 27 + 2*9 + 2*3 + 1, and if Rm is {0,p^m,2p^m,....(p-1)p^m}, then we have for a in Rm, b in Rk, that ab is in R(m+k), which seems very similar to the definition of a graded ring.

This extra structure gives rise to a simple proof of the group of units being cyclic (when p is an odd prime), so seems like helpful additional information to know about.

However since each subspace in this decomposition is not closed under addition, it seems like this isn't a graded ring, in which case, what is it?

Comment: You have a graded monoid (under multiplication).

Comment: The $\Bbb Z_p$-vector space structure you seem to be defining on $\Bbb Z/p^n$ doesn't involve the addition or multiplication operation on $\Bbb Z/p^n$, BTW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I think you are getting at is that $\newcommand{\Z}{\Bbb Z}\Z/p^n\Z$
is a filtered ring and that filtered rings have associated graded rings. A filtration of a commutative ring $R$ is a descending sequence of
ideals $I_0\supseteq I_1\supseteq I_2\supseteq\cdots$ such that $I_0=R$
and $I_m I_n\subseteq I_{m+n}$. The associated graded ring is $S=\bigoplus_{n=0}^\infty I_n/I_{n+1}$. It has a multiplication which maps
$(I_m/I_{m+1})\times  (I_n/I_{n+1})$ to $I_{m+n}/I_{m+n+1}$.

In your case, $I_k=p^k\Z/p^n\Z$ and each $I_k/I_{k+1}$ is a vector
space over $I_0/I_1\cong \Z/p\Z$, of dimension $1$ for $k <n$.

Comment: Thank you, this is just what I was after.